# Understanding (statement of) a theorem of Jack McLaughlin

Tags: reference-request, gr.group-theory, finite-groups

In the book *Twelve sporadic groups*, Griess states

> If $A$ is an abelian group, $G$ acts on $A$, $z\in Z(G)$ satisfies $z-1\in$ Aut$(G)$, then $H^n(G,A)=0$ for $n\geq 0$. This is an observation of Jack McLaughlin.

My first simple question is *what do we mean here by* $z-1\in$ Aut$(G)$?

Second question, I didn't get reference of it in google search; can one state a reference for a modern, elementary proof of it? (I mean, if a proof of this fact appeared in some book or recent papers, please state it.)

Comment: Is it a typo for $\operatorname{Aut}(A)$? I'd expect $z-1$ to mean $a \mapsto (z-1)a$: if this was invertable it would certainly imply $H^0(G,A)=0$.

Comment: Using the finite-groups tag is confusing, because there are no finiteness assumptions in this question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The statement is not identical, but it is the "center kills" argument, as in 149 page 42 of [these lecture notes](http://courses.washington.edu/mnotes/groupcoho/notes.pdf).

For $g \in Z(G)$, the map $m \mapsto gm$ is a ${\mathbb Z}G$-automorphism of $A$. The map it induces on the cohomology groups $H^n(G,A)$ is the so-called conjugation map $c_g$, and since $g \in G$, this is the identity map on $H^n(G,A)$. Of course, the same map with $g=1$, $m \mapsto m$ also induces the idenity on $H^n(G,A)$, so $g-1$ induces the zero map.

But if $g-1$ is an automorphism of $A$, then it is a ${\mathbb Z}G$-automorphism, and induces an automorphism of $H^n(G,A)$. So $H^n(G,A)=0$.